# C# WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I know that it's been here a million times but I don't know what's wrong in my code. I tried everything but the `ComboBox` is not binding `SelectedItem` correctly.
Here is my complete sandbox solution. You can also find it on GitHub (https://github.com/LukasNespor/ComboBoxBinding).

**BindableBase.cs**

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**ContactModel.cs**

```
public class ContactModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    private string _Phone;
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _Phone; }
        set
        {
            _Phone = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Phone));
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null || !(obj is ContactModel))
            return false;

        return ((ContactModel)obj).Id == this.Id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} {Phone}";
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    ...>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="200" Height="23"
              SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedContact}" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Contacts}" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        ViewModel.SelectedContact = new ContactModel
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Some Guy",
            Phone = "+123456789"
        };
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public List<ContactModel> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<ContactModel>
            {
                new ContactModel() {Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Phone = "+166666333" },
                new ContactModel() {Id = 2, Name = "Some Guy", Phone = "+123456789" }
            };
        }
    }

    private ContactModel _SelectedContact;
    public ContactModel SelectedContact
    {
        get { return _SelectedContact; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedContact = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedContact));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just answered this yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915147/combox-selecteditem-does-not-apply-when-restoring-from-serialized-viewmodel/39958839#39958839

Comment: @Will thank you! I made this Sandbox solution withou serialization by my real problem was in serialization and missing `JsonSerializerSettings` - track object instances.

Comment: Hah, ironic.  But you know now that the problem is the instances not being the same.  That's what @rom told you in his answer.  You should accept that as correct, as it does answer your question as it is described above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need do Sync the list with the current selected item:

1.Xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

2.ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ContactModel> Contacts { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _model = new Model {Name = "Prop Name" };
        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>
        {
            new ContactModel {Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Phone = "+166666333"},
            new ContactModel {Id = 2, Name = "Some Guy", Phone = "+123456789"}
        };
        SelectedContact = Contacts[0];
    }

    private ContactModel _SelectedContact;

    public ContactModel SelectedContact
    {
        get { return _SelectedContact; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedContact = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedContact));
        }
    }
```