# Issue with Binding for ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Below is the code

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbRegisteredDriveList"
          Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DriveList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDrive, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource NotConverter}}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource xxxx.ComboBoxItem.Style}">

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbTemplate" Width="250" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                           Text="{Binding VolumeLabel, Converter={StaticResource CenterEllipsisConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference tbTemplate}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

When ever we change the Volume Label for drive we are getting notification. But Selected item in combo box is not get refreshed. Can anyone help me on this. I want to display changed Volume Label for selected item in combo box.

```
public ObservableCollection<DiskDrive> _driveList;
public ObservableCollection<DiskDrive> DriveList { get { return _driveList; } }
private DiskDrive _selectedDrive;
public DiskDrive SelectedDrive
{
    get { return _selectedDrive; }
    set { _selectedDrive = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedDrive); } }
```

Also we are notifying it whenever it is needed.

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(() => DriveList);
NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedDrive);
```

In `class DiskDrive`, the property `VolumeLabel` is defined like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the volume name of this disk. This is the friendly name ("Stick").
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// When this class is used to identify a removed USB device, the Volume
/// property is set to String.Empty.
/// </remarks>
private string _volumeLabel;
public string VolumeLabel
{
    get { return _volumeLabel; }
    set { _volumeLabel = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? string.Format(LocalizationManager.Instance["XXXX"], SerialNumber) : value; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of  `SelectedDrive`?

Comment: How do you change the _VolumeLabel_?

Comment: Try `UpdateSourceTrigger` in your binding.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan The default for ComboBox.SelectedItem is already UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. Even if it weren't, that flag determines when the source is notified, and OP's problem is notifying the target. OP: Mode=TwoWay is the default.There's a general tendency for people to spend hours setting random properties of `Binding` when five minutes reading MSDN would be more productive.

Comment: OP: It's possible that you're not raising `PropertyChanged` for  `SelectedDrive` every time you should. It's also possible that you're setting `SelectedDrive` to an object that is not *considered equal to* any object found in `DriveList`. What is the type of the items in `DriveList`? Where are you getting the value of `SelectedDrive`?

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue. Then it will almost certainly be very simple to solve. As it is, all we can do is guess, which is a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: The instance within SelectedItem ***must be found within the ItemsSource collection***.  If you're getting the SelectedItem instance from somewhere else (query, deserialization, etc) you need to go look for the equivalent in ItemsSource and use THAT.  For more info, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915147/combox-selecteditem-does-not-apply-when-restoring-from-serialized-viewmodel/39958839#39958839

Comment: It seems more code is not required as DriveList is correctly updating comboBox. Issue is only with selected Item. Let's say if selected Item is "1Drive" and i am changing it to "2Drive". ComboBox is added with the "2Drive" new value but selectedItem is not changing with New value"2Drive".

Comment: Even if it is clear to you that more code is not required, it will explain the situation for potential answerers more precisely than words ever could. You say you change the 'selected item' 'but selectedItem is not changing'. Don't you think that code would be less ambiguous here? What exactly are you changing? The `SelectedItem`, the `SelectedDrive` or the `VolumeLabel` of your `SelectedDrive`?

Comment: Yes as i mentioned in my first comment that i am changing VolumeLabel. Need to display that as selected item.

Comment: If you are changing `VolumeLabel`, `SelectedDrive` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `VolumeLabel` must raise the `PropertyChanged` event when changed. Otherwise the binding will not be updated and most likely you will leak memory, too. But still this is only a guess as you still did not show the code required in the first two comments. Is it so hard to add these few lines?

Comment: public ObservableCollection<DiskDrive> _driveList;
        public ObservableCollection<DiskDrive> DriveList
        {
            get
            {
                return _driveList;
            }
        }

        private DiskDrive _selectedDrive;
        public DiskDrive SelectedDrive
        {
            get { return _selectedDrive; }
            set { _selectedDrive = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedDrive); }
        }
Also we are notifying it whenever it is needed.  NotifyPropertyChanged(() => DriveList);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedDrive);

Comment: As you said you are changing the `VolumeLabel` property, please also add the definition of this property to your post.

Comment: /// </remarks>
        private string _volumeLabel;
        public string VolumeLabel
        {
            get { return _volumeLabel; }
            set
            {
                _volumeLabel = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? string.Format(LocalizationManager.Instance["XXXX"], SerialNumber) : value;
            }
        }

Comment: /// <summary>
        /// Get the volume name of this disk. This is the friendly name ("Stick").
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// When this class is used to identify a removed USB device, the Volume
        /// property is set to String.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

`DiskDrive` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `VolumeLabel` must raise the `PropertyChanged` event when changed. Otherwise the binding will not be updated.

Also, please notice that you will most probably leak memory when binding to a property of a class which does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938416/a-memory-leak-may-occur-when-you-use-data-binding-in-windows-presentation-foundation).